# Delete button disappears abruptly when deleting and inserting a table view row simultaneously

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an editable `UITableView`. The user can delete rows. When he does another (non-deletable) row is inserted at the end of the table view. (So the total number of rows in that section remains the same.)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // update data model
    [self.dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // update table view
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        // delete row
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        // insert row at the end of the section
        NSIndexPath *indexPathForLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(kMaxComponents - 1) inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathForLastRow] withRowAnimation:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Works great. However, when I delete the *last* row of the table view the delete button disappears abruptly with no animation (and too late).

In this case a new row is inserted at the same `indexPath` where the other one was deleted. What happens is that the animation pushes the old cell to the left while the new cell moves in from the right. But only when the whole animation has finished the red delete button disappears suddenly.

[image: Delete button overlaps new cell]

How can I make the delete button disappear smoothly (with an animation)?

Comment: Anything within the same bracket of `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` will happen simultaneously. You could try to put the delete and the add in different calls to begin and end updates. Also, try adding an animation besides YES. The proper values here are things along the line of [UITableViewRowAnimationFade](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewRowAnimation)

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `UITableViewRowAnimation`. I changed that to the proper value. Yet changing that constant to different values doesn't seem to affect the animation in this context. I put the code inside `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on purpose. Because if I don't the `tableView:numberOfRows:inSection:` method will return a wrong value after deleting the row and that will cause the app to crash.

Comment: what object in the model does the newly inserted row correspond to? You delete an object from the model but do not add a new one. It could be that the since there is no specified data that the delegate tries to load, the cell does not properly display the animation

Comment: All cells obtain their data from an `NSMutableArray` except the last cell. The last cell contains only static data, a `UILabel` with text "add another cell". So when the user taps that cell another cell is added at its position, pushing the last cell down by one row. Now I want to restrict the number of rows that a user can add e.g. to a maximum of 5 cells. So if there are four data cells already in the table view and the user taps the "add another cell" row that last cell should be replaced by the fifth data cell instead of being pushed downwards by one row.

Comment: At that point I need to delete the static data cell with the text label "add another cell" and then insert a new data cell instead. So normally the table view has `dataArray.count + 1` cells but when the maximum number of rows is reached it has only `dataArray.count` cells because the static data cell is missing.